# "Failure to download extra data files" after installing ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, fonts, downloads

After fresh install 12.04 I && updating apt and system restart, I always get this annoying message after reboot :

> Failure to download extra data files
>
> The following packages requested additional data downloads after
>   package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could
>   not be processed.
>
> ttf-mscorefonts-installer
>
> The download will be attempted again later, or you can try the
>   download again now. Running this command requires an active Internet
>   connection.

But if I run attempt now, it shows flashing terminal window and like nothing happen. It'll happen again when I restart system.

I found someone have [this problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1999391) too, but he haven't replied yet.

- I'm a newbie here, please help.

Comment: In case someone looks for a solution to this problem for 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr), here is the text of the first and last messages for this release: "Data files for some packages could not be downloaded" and "This is a permanent failure that leaves these packages unusable on your system.  You may need to fix your Internet connection, then remove and reinstall the packages to fix this problem."

Comment: It seems there are two threads running on this bug in 16.04: (1) "['Failure to download extra data files' with ttf-mscorefonts-installer on Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/766491/)"; and (2) "[ttf-mscorefonts-installer failure to download extra data files on Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/806241/)"

Comment: As mentioned above, the current working solution has been proposed [for Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/766491/failure-to-download-extra-data-files-with-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-on-ubuntu/767826#767826). It should be the same for Ubuntu 12.04 as well.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

### Solution 1:

Connect to the internet and run this command below, to fix the error

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

This will reinstall the package, and download the data files needed to configure the package. Wait for some times to finish downloading. The download size is approximately 4MB.

### Solution 2:

1. Connect to the internet and go to [this sourceforge link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/corefonts/files/the%20fonts/final/) and download all the `.exe` files there except `wd97vwr32.exe` file.
2. Copy those files in your home directory.
3. Run this command to configure the package

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer
   ```

   - This will ask you whether you have downloaded microsoft fonts or not. Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select OK, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   - Then again you will be asked to enter the directory name for the downloaded files, Type the location of your home directory and  use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select *OK*, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

     For example, if your login name is `anwar`, the location will be `/home/anwar`, because I copied the downloaded files there.

Done! you have successfully configured and setup the package.

**Note:** *If the files cannot be downloaded due to 404 error, check the "Can't download?" section*

### What was the cause of the problem?

This package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` is used to download Microsoft's font files *(those files are made freely available by Microsoft)* from the Internet and install them. Since you must accept the EULA of Microsoft to use those font files, those fonts cannot be included in the package like other Free *(Free as freedom)* packages.

The problem was, somehow you get disconnected from Internet before downloading those files. So, is the message asking to download more data files.

### Can't download?

If you can't download the files due to **404** errors, I have prepared a tar.gz archive of the downloaded contents. You can download it from this [dropbox link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35619242/msttfcorefonts_cabs.tar.gz) and extract it to a folder. If you extract it to `/tmp/`, you'll type that directory after the `dpkg-reconfigure` command in Solution 2.

Comment: Solution 1 solved my problem on 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr). Shift-Tab to select "OK", then Enter and Enter again.

Comment: For the benefit of people looking for this solution, I'll add that you can get into this problem by installing Wine (wine is not mentioned on this page yet).

Comment: Solution 1 didn't work for me. I get the message "Hashtype mismatch" when it tried to download the font andale.ttf. Apparently the same problem is discussed and fixed at http://askubuntu.com/questions/543673/mscorefonts-problems

Comment: Solution 1 fails for me because of an error 404 (file not found) regarding http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe. Solution 2 fails for me because the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer` does not allow me to configure the package. (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Comment: @marianoju I just clicked the link and the font file is downloaded without any problem!! And `sudo dpkg-reconfigure` didn't allow you to configure because the font is already configured or you didn't agreed with the EULA

Comment: @Anwar a) I am glad that the SourceForge link works for you, but please see https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/404484 for a log file with multiple error 404 I encountered while trying to reinstall (not only with andale32, but also comic32 and arial32). b) Shouldn't `sudo dpkg-reconfigure` allow me to **re**configure even if the font has already _been_ configured? c) I did check and `mscorefonts-eula license has already been accepted`, so that is not the issue here.

Comment: b) `dpkg-reconfigure` doesn't do anything if the package is already configured. In this case, i simply suggest to remove the package using `sudo apt-get purge ` command and re-install.

Comment: @marianoju I've made the font links available from dropbox now. Try that link if you can't

Comment: If you're using solution #2 you might find this useful instead of downloading each file manually http://stackoverflow.com/a/41040791/773263

Comment: Solution 1 failed for me, but Solution 2 did the thing. No checksum errors.

Comment: The problem is caused by broken permissions as a result of an upgrade from Trusty to Xenial, so reinstalling the package won't accomplish anything except show you the permission error.

Comment: @Cerin the main question was about 'failure to download extra data file' error and that can be fixed following this answer,  so this cannot be downvoted for that reason. If you have different error, ask another question

Comment: Anwar, I am in the same situation as marianoju. None of these worked for me and none of the "this is why this happens" applies, either. The below Debian .deb solution worked fine, however.

Comment: The thought of getting hung up on linux for anything having to do with Microsoft makes me sort of sick inside. What is the consequence of removing `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` from my system / apt sources?

Comment: @Todd not very drastic. You lose some MS fonts only. Arial, Tahoma, Times new roman are some of them.

Comment: See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1607535

Comment: Solution 1 fails on my system with Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl, full error: "Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
  Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/andale32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch https://dronedata.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the fonts/final/andale32.exe  Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl

E: Download Failed"

Comment: @AaronFranke Try solution 2. Even other answers

Comment: For me solution 1 failed with the python script that does the installation giving a FileNotFoundError: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/courie32.exe'`. It seemed like everything else worked and I don't know if the fonts were actually downloaded, but the missing ttf files were still causing me errors for other stuff (i.e when calling `ubuntu-support-status`). In case this happens to you, I recommend also trying @muaad-elsharif 's answer, it worked for me.

Comment: When I run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer` I get `Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
  Redirection from https to 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mirrorproblem?failedmirror=netix.dl.sourceforge.net' is forbidden [IP: 87.121.121.2 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the fonts/final/andale32.exe  Redirection from https to 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mirrorproblem?failedmirror=netix.dl.sourceforge.net' is forbidden [IP: 87.121.121.2 443]
E: Download Failed`

Comment: Download Failed

Answer (score 85):

I went to [Debian's site](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/download) and downloaded the ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6 and installed it using Gdeb, installed successfully.

Command-line example:

```
wget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

None of the other solutions posted here worked for me.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer ;)

Comment: Works well, is there any https link though?

Comment: @Mark I had it before Zanna edited the answer, here you go:
https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/download

Comment: +1 this works really good :) but why hasn't this version ended up in Ubuntu's repository tho..

Comment: @angulared I don't know to be honest, but I'm glad it works for everyone :)

Comment: I installed this using gdebi and worked!

Comment: Real cause is bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1607535 - it *may* be fixed in Ubuntu because backporting takes too much time for some reason.

Comment: +1. Thank you. This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue... So, this is my workaround to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
cd /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads
sudo rm partial/*
sudo rmdir partial
sudo mkdir partial
sudo chmod 777 partial
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo rm partial/*
sudo rmdir partial
sudo mkdir partial
sudo chmod 744 partial
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been getting this bug on Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10 and most solutions weren't helping me.  

This one seemed to fix it right away, got Times New Roman working in Libre Office Writer, and got texts to display properly again in Firefox.

Big help.

Comment: As previous comment, worked for me on 16.04 when others didn't. Thanks :)

Comment: This worked once for me, but now I'm getting `E: Failed to fetch https://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the fonts/final/arialb32.exe  404  Not Found`. It looks like good old Sourceforge is removing the necessary files.

Answer (score 4):

If you're getting:

> Get:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe [969 B]
>   Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
>   Hash Sum mismatch Fetched 969 B in 1s (660 B/s)
>   W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file
>   '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/andale32.exe'
>   couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission
>   denied) E: Failed to fetch
>   http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mir...ourceforge.net  Hash Sum
>   mismatch
>
> E: Download Failed

Try this:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/*
```

Followed by:

```
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

See [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323229) for more details.

Comment: Just tried that but now I get an issue with arial:
Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arial32.exe                                
  Hash Sum mismatch

Comment: Worked fine on Lubuntu 16.04! Thx!

Comment: _apt privilege error came again but this time it was far better. I saw fonts installing one by one. No Error. Only Warnings. Now Fonts appear in LibreOffice.

Answer (score 2):

Mine works with reinstalling it (found the command here and just try it out but then it worked. lol)

Uninstall command

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Install command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: This answer works for me unlike accepted one. Purge before reinstal is a key.

Comment: Fails with: `Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arialb32.exe
  Redirection from https to 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mirrorproblem?failedmirror=vorboss.dl.sourceforge.net' is forbidden [IP: 5.10.152.194 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://vorboss.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the fonts/final/arialb32.exe  Redirection from https to 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mirrorproblem?failedmirror=vorboss.dl.sourceforge.net' is forbidden [IP: 5.10.152.194 443]
E: Download Failed
`

Comment: Same here @SergeStroobandt

Comment: @FabianoLothor Try [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1127190/164341) instead!

Answer (score 2):

## Stop the nagging, install & refresh font cache

To stop the nagging about `Failure to download extra data files`, first **remove the partial download:**

```
$ sudo rm -R /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/
```

Then, **download and install** the Debian version of this package:

```
$ wget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
$ rm ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

Finally, grab this opportunity to **update the font cache:**

```
$ sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

## For Ansible automation

```
- name: 'Removing buggy MicroSoft™ core fonts installer.'
  apt:
    pkg: ttf-mscorefonts-installer
    state: absent

- name: 'Removing partial download of MicroSoft™ core fonts.'
  file:
    path: '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/'
    state: absent

- name: 'Installing Debian MicroSoft™ core fonts installer.'
  # https://askubuntu.com/a/1127190/164341
  apt:
      deb: 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb'
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the package **ttf-mscorefonts-installer** and then install **ubuntu-restricted-extras**.

Connect to the internet and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

After the next start-up of your system, the message will be gone.

(I had the same problem but with even one more package in the message: *flashplugin-installer*)
this is the annoying message I get every start:
[image]

The whole message is very long, rightklick to download it:
[image: this is the annoying message i get every start]

Maybe you have to restart the system before install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: Why should he uninstall the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, any reason? note that `ubuntu-restricted-extras` also install it as a dependency. So, what is the point?

Comment: yes, there is a reason, becouse it works!

Comment: It sounds really strange, but i guess, there is a bug somewhere in apt-get: bcause even if you remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer even with purge, the message that it is missing still stays after a reboot! This is a really strange behaviour, but the only solution is to uninstall all that is related to that bug and reinstall the ubuntu-restricted-extras afterwards after a reboot. I had this strange behaviour on two mashines already

Comment: @rubo77 I cannot really confirm this...

Comment: it only worked, cause on my computer gksudo was installed. i added a new answer, that should work on kubuntu fresh install too

Answer (score 0):

The above question is related to [this other one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463754/how-to-make-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-package-download-fonts-after-it-says-it-i).

None of the solutions provided at both questions worked for me. Hence, I decided to:

### Manually install the truetype fonts

Below are the 10 steps you need to follow in order to manually install the Microsoft core truetype fonts. Unless otherwise indicated, all commands must be executed inside a shell terminal window. In most *Ubuntu distros, the **Ctrl Alt T** key combo (keyboard shortcut) is one of the ways you can open a new shell terminal window.

1. Purge the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package and clean your APT cache of DEB packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer -y ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get check ; sudo apt-get clean ; sudo apt-get autoremove -y
   ```
2. Install/update the **Thunar** file manager (it will be further needed to rename all downloaded truetype fonts):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yuri-sucupira/thunar1.6.10-fix ; sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv AF8C7F18 ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get check ; sudo apt-get install thunar --reinstall -y ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
   ```
3. Install/update the **7z** file archiver (it's a file compactor/compressor and extractor/decompressor required to extract the truetype fonts from inside the EXE files that you'll have to download):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install p7zip p7zip-full --reinstall -y
   ```
4. Create a temporary `fonts` folder by running this shell command:

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/fonts
   ```
5. Start a web browser (like Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome or any other one you might be using), then go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/corefonts/files/the%20fonts/final/ and **download all EXE files except wd97vwr32.exe** (because wd97vwr32.exe is a Word 97 Viewer: not a truetype font file). All the downloaded EXE files must be placed at `/tmp/fonts`
6. Change directory (CD) into that temporary folder:

   ```
   cd /tmp/fonts
   ```
7. Extract the contents of all the downloaded EXE files:

   ```
   7z e andale32.exe ; 7z e arial32.exe ; 7z e arialb32.exe ; 7z e comic32.exe ; 7z e courie32.exe ; 7z e georgi32.exe ; 7z e impact32.exe ; 7z e times32.exe ; 7z e trebuc32.exe ; 7z e verdan32.exe ; 7z e webdin32.exe
   ```
8. Copy all TTF (truetype font) files into your system's Microsoft truetype fonts folder:

   ```
   sudo cp /tmp/fonts/*.TTF /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
   ```

   - Note: if `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/` doesn't exist, create it by running the shell command `sudo mkdir /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/`
9. Start Thunar in superuser mode, inside the Microsoft truetype fonts folder:

   ```
   sudo thunar /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
   ```
10. Now, at the new Thunar window (path: `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/`), go to the Thunar menu and then select the option **Edit** and then hit **Select all files**. Then hit the **F2** key (or go to the Edit menu option and click on **Rename...**, or still right-click onto the area where the files were selected and choose the **Rename...** option), change the first field on the left to **Uppercase / Lowercase** (if you need an example, take a look at [this picture](http://10629-presscdn-0-58.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/pictures/2011/03/Bulk_Rename_Uppercase_Lowercase.png)) and then change the right-side field to **Name and suffix**. Finally, at the `Convert to:` field, change its parameter to **lowercase** and then hit the **Rename files** button.

...and that's it!

If you did everything as explained here, you'll now have all the Microsoft core truetype fonts installed. Start e.g. LibreOffice Writer and check if fonts such as Arial and Comic Sans are available. If they are, the fonts were correctly added to your system.

PS: the leftovers at `/tmp/fonts` will be eliminated on the next system (re)boot. Hence, you don't need to worry about them.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the “Failure to download extra data files” problem after running 'sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras' in Ubuntu 18.04.

I fixed the problem with these two terminal commands issued while in ~/Downloads:

`wget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.7_all.deb
sudo gdebi ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.7_all.deb`

Good Luck.
(If gdebi is not already installed then 'sudo apt install gdebi' beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

look for the file gksudo

```
which gksudo
```

and for kdesudo

```
which kdesudo
```

since i use kubuntu, gksudo is missing when the automated script is trying to download the missing files.

that's the bug!!

workaround:
i solved it with a symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/kdesudo /usr/bin/gksudo
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-restricted-extras ttf-mscorefonts-installer flashplugin-installer
sudo restart
```

after the restart:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras flashplugin-installer
```

later you can remove that ugly workaround-symlink again with:

```
sudo rm -i /usr/bin/gksudo
```

Quite a hammermethod but it works

Comment: Please have a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/412941/184942).

Comment: I guess, you can uninstall `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `flashplugin-installer` after al problems are solved

Answer (score -1):

You might have trouble getting `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` to accept the EULA.

These commands will accept the EULA and reinstall the packages (assuming you downloaded the individual font `.exe`s):

```
echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: That was not my problem, I've reacepted the EULA after using some other reinstall method, and problem persists. OMG, Ubuntu...