# Mscorefonts problems

Tags: fonts, 14.10

I tried installing `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` from the terminal, because I want to use Wine.

It looked kind of like it failed on the Comic Sans part. Viewing it just displays the text in another font.

Then this Failure to download extra data files window popped up.

[image]

I tried uninstalling ttf-mscorefonts-installer from the terminal and then reinstalling it by following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463754/cant-download-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-on-ubuntu-14-04/463760#463760). This time it failed to fetch the first font, andale32.exe. I got an error message that said: `invalid content-range header`.

What should I do?

Comment: Curiously I tried downloading the Adele TTF but it looks like it was rolling in the deep because I could not download it. Rumor has it that if I take it all I'll be able to download it. So I'll be waiting.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I fixed it.

Download and install [this](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb) via software-center and boom! It's working :D

Comment: Is this still the case in 2016?

Comment: @MrMesees, I think so. I'm running 16.04 and bumped into this problem on my last update.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem for me on Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 71):

Same problem, found a solution

1. Install the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, we need some things from the package later

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
   ```
2. Download and install the fonts

   ```
   TMP=$(mktemp -d)
   cd "$TMP"
   awk '/Url/ {system("wget "$2)}' /usr/share/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer
   sudo /usr/lib/msttcorefonts/update-ms-fonts "$TMP"/*
   ```
3. Avoid future error message

   ```
   sudo touch /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer
   ```
4. Housekeeping

   ```
   cd ..
   rm -r "$TMP"
   ```

<sub>[primary source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1371783)</sub>

Problem solved **;)**

Comment: Seems to have worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu 16.04.  Thank you for providing such a clear answer with copy and paste ready instructions.

Comment: Just tested this on Ubuntu 16.04 and works perfect!

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing with these commands, and why?

Answer (score 9):

A straight-forward option **work-around** can be implemented as follows using a Debian repo (reliable):

```
sudo apt-get -y remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb -P ~/Downloads
sudo apt install ~/Downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

Hopefully, the Ubuntu repo version will be fixed soon.

Comment: This is the only workaround that actually worked for me (January 2017), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As for a freshly set up Ubuntu 64-bit 15.04 with all extras also installed during installation, Wine stopped half-ways in the process, and it was connected to the mscorefonts, with the repeated error message given above. After waiting some hours, I quit the software center, and rebooted. The following lines cured the problem completely and set up the mscorefonts correctly, as far as I can tell. Explanation is given underneath.

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo dpkg --configure -a
cd
sudo wget downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
sudo wine andale32
rm andale32.exe
```

The first line tells that the second line (the dpkg) has to be performed, to complete wine installation. Then, when this takes places, it tells that andale32.exe is not as expected (in hash value, which probably refers to an earlier version of it or such). Assuming that it is okay, it is then manually installed, in this case by running 'sudo' in front of wine, which may not be necessary. After the final line and a wait, the question of whether to accept the fonts arises as a nice window. A repeat of the --fix-missing reports no need for additional commands.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this try removing and re-installing `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` from the terminal only - there are some prompts which need to be answered, and are not always done properly in a graphical window:

Open a terminal with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

Enter the following commands

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: Nope, it failed. Edit: Weird. Tried again and now it failed at arial instead.

Comment: @AnAwesomeMiner Did it yield any error messages?

Comment: It failedd to fetch arial32.exe. Hash Sum Mishmatch.

Comment: @AnAwesomeMiner If it helps, you seem to be not alone in this.  You might indicate to launchpad that you are also experiencing this problem. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1371783

Comment: @AnAwesomeMiner On [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2244924.html) there is also a thread about this problem