# Error with ttf-mscorefonts-installer when installing Skype on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: skype

I got this error after using one of the askubuntu articles to install skype on my ubuntu:

```
Data files for some packages could not be downloaded

The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.

ttf-mscorefonts-installer

This is a permanent failure that leaves these packages unusable on your system.  You may need to fix your Internet connection, then remove and reinstall the packages to fix this problem.
```

This may have been a result of the errors I got on [Errors with Installing Skype on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671978/errors-with-installing-skype-on-ubuntu-14-04), which I still haven't received an answer for.

Should I do anything? The error is alarming.

Also, I'm not so sure that this is because of Skype, but putting 2 and 2 together, it seems likely.

Comment: I commented a fix on your other question, you should solve that one first and then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before proceeding with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

If it can't be found, you have to enable the `multiverse` repository in your <kbd>System Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd> first.

Running the command will probably prompt you to accept the Microsoft Licence (EULA). You have to do this, or the installation will abort. This is also the reason why this package can't be installed non-interactively.

After that, try installing `skype` again.

Comment: The package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` seems to have a problem, maybe helpful: http://askubuntu.com/a/657005/367165

Comment: I just reinstalled the operating system, too many problems.