# Error when trying to install, debconf resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: package-management, software-center

I'm trying to run webgl apps in my web browser but whenever I try to, nothing happens. I found that `ubuntu-restricted-extras` can be installed to enable webgl. One of my friends installed the package on their system and was able to run the webgl app that I was trying to run. When I tried to install the package using the Ubuntu software center, the download stalled so I had to kill the process.

Output  of  `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python-cssselect python-queuelib python-w3lib
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 145 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/27.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 134 kB of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 286934 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output of  `apt-cache policy ubuntu-restricted-extras`

```
$ apt-cache policy ubuntu-restricted-extras
ubuntu-restricted-extras:
  Installed: 60.1
  Candidate: 60.1
  Version table:
 *** 60.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     60 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

What is causing the problem with the installation?

Comment: The update system is locked by another process, probably the one you killed.  Easiest fix is probably to reboot.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'll try that and see if it works.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The installation seems to have worked, but the webgl app is still not working when I run it in firefox.

Comment: Sorry, I was just addressing the installation problem, which is why I posted it as a comment, rather than an answer.  I know nothing about webgl.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` and the output of `apt-cache policy ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: @A.B. I just added the output for both commands.

Comment: Have you restarted your system in the meantime?

Comment: Answer finished. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Enable WebGL In Chrome On Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/299345/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Answer (score 0):

The package `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is installed as you can see in the output of the command `apt-cache policy ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Now there are three commands to repair your system.

```
sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

---

If you have problems to install `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/657005/367165).

Comment: I used all of the commands but the webgl still isn't running. What is ```ttf-mscorefonts-installer``` ? Also, for the other post that you provided the link for, should I use your answer that you posted?

Comment: You have asked three questions at once: 1) webgl 2) ubuntu-restricted-extras 3) DbDriver "config"

Comment: Your question was "Error when trying to install ubuntu-restricted-extras". The problem is solved. Webgl is answered here http://askubuntu.com/questions/299345/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome-on-ubuntu

Comment: I tried that answer already, it was only addressing enabling webgl on chrome. It didn't seem to work before.