# Ubuntu Restricted Extras package fails to complete Installation in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I have a persistent USB installation of Ubuntu 14.04.  Firefox would not play MPeg4, AAC or QuickTime -- so I tried to install the "restricted-extras".  The install progress bar went 3/4 to 4/5th of the way and then after a long delay the Window went "dim" and eventually the OS indicated "No Response" from the process.

I tried several times all with the same result - even rebuilding the Ubuntu installation.

Even with the partial installation Firefox would now play videos - but when I went to install Wine and Mono they both would not even start due to missing dependencies.  I am suspect of the "fonts" (supposedly to be installed by the package) that they may not be there because the process locked-up and quit, that perhaps Wine and Mono want them but I just don't know and although a professional I am very new to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, please run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

You will see two dialogues popping up in your terminal that require you to accept the EULA (End User License Agreement) of some packages (one of them is `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`).
Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the `<OK>` or `<YES>` buttons (will get highlighted with red background) and confirm with <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>.

Your GUI installation has probably not finished because it failed to ask you to confirm those two dialogues. The reinstall through the terminal will prompt them to you again and fix the problem.

---

In case the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` fails to download the necessary components, you need to purge this again and install the `.deb` package in version 3.6 from the Debian server.

Run this command to purge the defect `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package:

```
sudo apt-get purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Then **either** download the newer package for Debian from [here](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb) and open/install it through the Software Center - **or** run the following set of commands to do the same through the terminal:

```
wget -q 'http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb'
sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

If you want, you may delete the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb` file again after the successful installation.

<sub>The second part of this answer about repairing a broken `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` is derived from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/543690/367990) by user [AnAwesomeMiner](https://askubuntu.com/users/130492/anawesomeminer).</sub>