# ttf-mscorefonts-installer 3.7 failure dialog still appearing

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, 18.10

On 18.10, I'm still seeing the zombie `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` “Failure to download extra data files” dialog every time I restart my computer.

This is a vintage bug that has been causing woe for Ubuntu users since at least 2012. I am aware of other questions and answers about this issue, but none of the solutions have worked in this case. For reference, notable prior questions are:

- ["Failure to download extra data files" after installing ttf-mscorefonts-installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153928/failure-to-download-extra-data-files-after-installing-ttf-mscorefonts-installe) (2012)
- [Failure to download extra data files - ttf-mscorefonts-installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852302/failure-to-download-extra-data-files-ttf-mscorefonts-installer) (2016)
- ["Failure to download extra data files" with ttf-mscorefonts-installer on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766491/failure-to-download-extra-data-files-with-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-on-ubuntu) (2016)

Previous solutions include:

**Deleting partially downloaded files**

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/
```

This directory does not exist on my system. There are no partially downloaded files to delete.

Sometimes an empty file is created when the failure dialog appears at:

```
/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer.failed
```

It does not make any difference if I delete this file or rename it to `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` as answers to other previous questions have suggested.

**Installing a newer version from a Debian package**

In the past, it was version 3.4 causing problems and users could download and install version 3.6 from a Debian repository like so:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
# Also sometimes suggested:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Later a Debian package for 3.7 became available and this method apparently worked for some users using 3.7.

The latest version available in the repositories seems to be the curiously-named `3.7ubuntu4~really3.6ubuntu3`. Which appears to be “newer” than the Debian 3.7 package from the system's point of view.

I have tried installing both the system version and the 3.7 Debian package, purging previous installations beforehand, and the failure dialog still appears.

**Download fonts manually**

Some answers offer links to the font files contained in the package and suggest downloading them manually to the target directory. In my case, the fonts are all already there in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/`. Downloading and replacing them from other sources doesn't help, the dialog still appears.

I have tried all combinations of previous solutions in all the orders I can think of and nothing solves the problem.

What else can I try to prevent this insistent dialog from appearing?

Answer (score 7):

Manually download the Debian v3.7 package, purge the Ubuntu version and then install the Debian package.  That'll successfully download all the files.

```
wget http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.7_all.deb

sudo apt-get purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer

sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.7_all.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for this, on Ubuntu 19.04 this was driving me mad on each boot. Works like a charm.

Comment: The downloads currently take a looooong time. Be patient when running the installer.

Comment: I usually put `sudo apt-mark hold ttf-mscorefonts-installer` before installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: Confirmed to work also for Lubuntu 19.04 and 19.10. I think it should be topped off with the: sudo fc-cache -f -v

Answer (score 1):

There is another bug report on Canonical's website you can try:

- [Update-notiifier - Failure to download extra data file](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/673156)

In this report there were two issues:

- EULA (End User License Agreement) not accepted by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Left over symbolic links needed to be manually removed:

> ```
> sudo rm /etc/alternatives/nvidia_settings_conf
> sudo rm /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
> sudo rm /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia_settings.conf
> sudo rm /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf
> ```