# ttf-mscorefonts-installer failure to download extra data files on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, fonts

I know it's been asked before, but I can't leave comments yet, and when I tried to ask about it as an answer to one of the other similar questions, I've been frowned upon.

So, my case:
[Failed To download extra data files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhmiX.png)

1) I tried to remove /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/*
as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/a/682326/574648
I accepted EULA terms.
I've got:

```
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common (3.168.1) ...
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe 
  Could not open file /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/andale32.exe - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch http://pilotfiber.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the fonts/final/andale32.exe  Could not open file /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/andale32.exe - open (2: No such file or directory)

E: Download Failed
Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ...
```

(I have to mention that I've tried it before several times without cleaning /partials/ and I had Hash Sum mismatch issues)

```
dpkg -s ttf-mscorefonts-installerPackage: ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: contrib/fonts
Installed-Size: 131
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: msttcorefonts
Version: 3.4+nmu1ubuntu2
Provides: msttcorefonts
Depends: cabextract, xfonts-utils, update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2)
Pre-Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0
Recommends: fonts-liberation
Description: Installer for Microsoft TrueType core fonts
 This package allows for easy installation of the Microsoft True Type
 Core Fonts for the Web including:
 .
   Andale Mono
   Arial Black
   Arial (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Comic Sans MS (Bold)
   Courier New (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Georgia (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Impact
   Times New Roman (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Trebuchet (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Verdana (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Webdings
 .
 You will need an Internet connection to download these fonts if you
 don't already have them.
 .
 NOTE: the package fonts-liberation contains free variants of the Times,
 Arial and Courier fonts. It's better to use those instead unless you
 specifically need one of the other fonts from this package.
Original-Maintainer: Thijs Kinkhorst <thijs@debian.org>
```

2) I have tried to simply reinstall the package(accepting EULA and everything):
https://askubuntu.com/a/543683/574648

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Nothing changed.

I've got:

```
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
  Could not open file /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/andale32.exe - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to fetch http://pilotfiber.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the fonts/final/andale32.exe  Could not open file /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/andale32.exe - open (2: No such file or directory)

E: Download Failed
Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ...



dpkg -s ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Package: ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: contrib/fonts
Installed-Size: 131
Recommends: fonts-liberation
Description: Installer for Microsoft TrueType core fonts
 This package allows for easy installation of the Microsoft True Type
 Core Fonts for the Web including:
 .
   Andale Mono
   Arial Black
   Arial (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Comic Sans MS (Bold)
   Courier New (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Georgia (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Impact
   Times New Roman (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Trebuchet (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Verdana (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Webdings
 .
 You will need an Internet connection to download these fonts if you
 don't already have them.
 .
 NOTE: the package fonts-liberation contains free variants of the Times,
 Arial and Courier fonts. It's better to use those instead unless you
 specifically need one of the other fonts from this package.
Original-Maintainer: Thijs Kinkhorst <thijs@debian.org>
```

3) Then I tried this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/543690/574648
The installation via the Ubuntu Softrawe Centre went well, it didn't ask to accept any T&C.

```
dpkg -s ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Package: ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: contrib/fonts
Installed-Size: 125
Maintainer: Thijs Kinkhorst <thijs@debian.org>
Architecture: all
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: msttcorefonts
Version: 3.6
Provides: msttcorefonts
Depends: wget, cabextract, xfonts-utils, debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0
Recommends: fonts-liberation
Description: Installer for Microsoft TrueType core fonts
 This package allows for easy installation of the Microsoft True Type
 Core Fonts for the Web including:
 .
   Andale Mono
   Arial Black
   Arial (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Comic Sans MS (Bold)
   Courier New (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Georgia (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Impact
   Times New Roman (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Trebuchet (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Verdana (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
   Webdings
 .
 You will need an Internet connection to download these fonts if you
 don't already have them.
 .
 NOTE: the package fonts-liberation contains free variants of the Times,
 Arial and Courier fonts. It's better to use those instead unless you
 specifically need one of the other fonts from this package.
```

Nothing changed. The annoying notification again.

4) Lastly, I download all 11 exes manually, as suggested in Solution 2 in https://askubuntu.com/a/168377/574648
and reconfigured the package(v.3.4, it simply didn't do anything for 3.6 installed via Ubuntu Software Centre):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer

You are free to download these fonts and use them for your own use,
but you may not redistribute them in modified form, including changes
to the file name or packaging format.

Extracting cabinet: /home/yuranos/Downloads/fonts//andale32.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting andale.inf
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting AndaleMo.TTF
  extracting ADVPACK.DLL
  extracting W95INF32.DLL
  extracting W95INF16.DLL

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /home/yuranos/Downloads/fonts//arial32.exe
  extracting FONTINST.EXE
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Ariali.TTF
  extracting Arialbd.TTF
  extracting Arialbi.TTF
  extracting Arial.TTF

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /home/yuranos/Downloads/fonts//arialb32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting AriBlk.TTF

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /home/yuranos/Downloads/fonts//comic32.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Comicbd.TTF
  extracting Comic.TTF
  extracting fontinst.exe

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /home/yuranos/Downloads/fonts//courie32.exe
  extracting cour.ttf
  extracting courbd.ttf
  extracting courbi.ttf
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting couri.ttf
  extracting fontinst.exe

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /home/yuranos/Downloads/fonts//georgi32.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Georgiaz.TTF
  extracting Georgiab.TTF
  extracting Georgiai.TTF
  extracting Georgia.TTF
  extracting fontinst.exe

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /home/yuranos/Downloads/fonts//impact32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting Impact.TTF
  extracting fontinst.inf

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /home/yuranos/Downloads/fonts//times32.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Times.TTF
  extracting Timesbd.TTF
  extracting Timesbi.TTF
  extracting Timesi.TTF
  extracting FONTINST.EXE

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /home/yuranos/Downloads/fonts//trebuc32.exe
  extracting FONTINST.EXE
  extracting trebuc.ttf
  extracting Trebucbd.ttf
  extracting trebucbi.ttf
  extracting trebucit.ttf
  extracting fontinst.inf

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /home/yuranos/Downloads/fonts//verdan32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Verdanab.TTF
  extracting Verdanai.TTF
  extracting Verdanaz.TTF
  extracting Verdana.TTF

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /home/yuranos/Downloads/fonts//webdin32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting Webdings.TTF
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Licen.TXT

All done, no errors.
All fonts downloaded and installed.
```

Guess what? The same annoying window appears again shortly after the installation.
It's so disappointing. I've spend so much time already on such a trivial issue.

Comment: Leaving the error message aside, can you use the fonts? Asking since this seems to be similar to [bug #1570141](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1570141).

Comment: Do you really need these fonts or is it just the error message? I blacklisted ttf-mscorefonts-installer and flashplugin-installer on all my machines as described in [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/76075/40581). You could to that, remove the package and the message should be gone. If you actually need one of the fonts you could install it by opening it in the font viewer and installing it there or placing ~/.local/share/fonts/ or the corresponding directory in /usr.

Comment: Thanks you, guys! I haven't used Linux for 5 years, so I would kindly ask you to elaborate. I'm not sure I'm checking it correctly, but from what I see when I open LibreOffice docs that are using Windows fonts: without the package the texts are corrupted. With the latest fix(4) even Andale Mono is available. In any case, I'd like to have the fonts, but I don't care if 1 of them is not available, if the rest are. Can I just silence the  notification? Is it done with the apt-pinning?

Comment: Ok, then you have (most of) the fonts. Good. As regards the notification, it only pops up when you install/reinstall the package, right? In that case, just ignore it and move on. :)

Comment: Thanks, Gunnar! As far as I see, but I can double-check again, the notification pops up on every reboot. So, I'd rather get rid of it if it's at all possible without deleting the package.

Comment: On every reboot sounds annoying. I suspect it's somehow related to the bug I mentioned. Or maybe you should file a new bug, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, I checked. It appears again after a reboot.

Comment: Sorry, I can't add comments yet. Here is the answer: [Failure to download extra data files - ttf-mscorefonts-installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852302/)