# ttf-mscorefonts-installer data download error popup

Tags: package-management, fonts

How do I get past this error message, so I don't keep seeing the ttf-mscorefonts-installer error popup?

It's NOT the licence acceptance issue, apparently. It seems to be that the http protocol has been deprecated in libcurl, and the installer is trying to access an exe file from a http website.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 18 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/29.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 307868 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb ...
mscorefonts-eula license has already been accepted
Unpacking ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) over (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common (3.168.2) ...
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: processing...
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http: //downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
Err:1 h ttp://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
  Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/andale32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch https ://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the fonts/final/andale32.exe  Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl

E: Download Failed
Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ...
```

(NB - I addded extra spaces to break the links because I don't have sufficient reputation points!)

Answer (score 10):

There seems to be a bug with the latest `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, but here is a way around it.

As first uninstall it completely, to make sure when you later install it you accept the EULA.

```
sudo apt remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

then install it again and as said make sure you accept the EULA by tabbing to untill the 'O.k.' field is highlighted and press <kbd>Return</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

untill now you might are facing still the same bug this were gonna change now by craeting a folder in the `/tmp` directory and downloading the fonts into it.

```
TMP=$(mktemp -d)
cd "$TMP"
awk '/Url/ {system("wget "$2)}' /usr/share/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

with this out of the way you can begin to update your corefonts

```
sudo /usr/lib/msttcorefonts/update-ms-fonts "$TMP"/*
```

after this is done al you need to do is cleaning up

```
sudo touch /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/ttf-mscorefonts-installer
cd ..
rm -r "$TMP"
```

([Solution found here](https://askubuntu.com/a/657005/522934))

Comment: Works for Elementary OS as well