# Installed PlayonLinux and this annoying update message keep popping up

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I have install PlayonLinux a few days ago to experiment with Windows game.... but since then, this message keep popping up everytime my laptop boot up..

```
    Failure to download extra data files

The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.

ttf-mscorefonts-installer

The download will be attempted again later, or you can try the download again now.  Running this command requires an active Internet connection.
```

I already un-install PlayonLinux and this still appear on every boot up.

I have try all the solution listed on this post, from 4 years ago.

["Failure to download extra data files" after installing ttf-mscorefonts-installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153928/failure-to-download-extra-data-files-after-installing-ttf-mscorefonts-installe)

Yeah, the message still pop up.. So I hope someone can help me remove this annoying pop up.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try solution 2 and further?

Answer (score 0):

PlayOnWindows will also install a few other programs, including `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, which downloads and installs some fonts from Microsoft. It downloads the fonts from an unstable location, and is currently having trouble. If you wait a while, it will probably manage to install them, and then give you no more trouble. Alternatively, you can remove the Microsoft font installer thus:

```
apt purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

This will remove the program, and it will no longer attempt to install Microsoft fonts.