# Unable to install Win font on Ubuntu. couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, fonts

I am trying to install Windows font on Ubuntu 16.04. It says package has installed when I try to reinstall the same package but fonts are not found on LibreOffice. Also, while installing it gives some error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Reading package lists...
Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   ttf-mscorefonts-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/29.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 134 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package ttf-mscorefonts-installer
(Reading database ... 208570 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb ...
mscorefonts-eula license has already been accepted
Unpacking ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common (3.168.2) ... ttf-mscorefonts-installer: processing...
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe Get:1
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe [198 kB]
Fetched 198 kB in 5s (35.9 kB/s)                                      
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/andale32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arial32.exe Get:1
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arial32.exe [554 kB]
Fetched 554 kB in 4s (124 kB/s)                                       
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/arial32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied) ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arialb32.exe Get:1
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arialb32.exe [969 B] Err:1
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arialb32.exe               
Hash Sum mismatch Fetched 969 B in 2s (367 B/s)                       
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/arialb32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mirrorproblem?failedmirror=excellmedia.dl.sourceforge.net Hash Sum mismatch
E: Download Failed
```

[image: Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ..]

I followed [this step](https://askubuntu.com/a/785330/118354). There still some Warning (W) was visible but No Error (E).
Warning is basically this:

```
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/webdin32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

**But after the steps mentioned in the link, I can see Window Font appear in LibreOffice font selection list.**

Old Update Information Dialog Box still came. Not sure if it is coming due to old process or due to this one.

**Do I need to take any more steps or everything is fine?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding **ttf-mscorefonts-installer**  I thought I'd share since I spent a few minutes on it when upgrading to yakkety.  I experienced both the the not-signed EULA, lack of priviliges and hash sum mismatch, strangely not all at the same time. All cured by :

```
chown _apt /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads
chown _apt /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial
rm /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/*
apt install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

What package maintainer that has the key to get this right I don't know.

Comment: As regards the privileges warning, it's the maintainer of apt. He [does not seem very keen on fixing it](https://bugs.debian.org/813786), though.

Comment: This should be helpful.

Comment: No warning etc now after following above steps. Added `sudo` in every steps.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson What to do! I install Linux every time as a replacement of Windows. But 10 years back also I need to fix it and now also Linux is linux. Fixing required for common things as well. After all that still graphics/fonts etc doesnot match.

Comment: @SatyaPrakash: "Does not match" sounds like a new question to me.

Comment: Yes, that is. But that is more of unpleasure that Linux don't work like a layman destop. I used this fix for that- `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`

Answer (score 1):

It's two things mixed up:

"Can't drop privileges..." is a warning, which you can just ignore. That warning is usually followed by a confirmation that the file was downloaded.

However, the attempt to fetch `arialb32.exe` was a real failure ("Hash Sum mismatch"). May be caused by a temporary server glitch; you can try again by reinstalling:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: After that I followed a link (http://askubuntu.com/a/785330/118354) which I have mentioned above. That has installed all.

Comment: @SatyaPrakash: Aha, missed that. Then all is well.

Answer (score -1):

As I said in the question itself that [following link](https://askubuntu.com/a/785330/118354) has solved but few warning was there so I wanted to get reply.

Main problem for me was Firefox. Font was looking very small. Unity Tweet tool has not proved useful for me. [This tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2911509/how-to-make-linuxs-desktop-look-good-on-high-resolution-displays.html) has worked it seems. Text are looking better. There `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` has made text readable. I am using value = 1.2 instead of suggested value 2.