# Unable to reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: 16.04, .ttf

The command is giving no results `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

i referred to the solution 2 of this answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/168377/640457 but the command is giving no output. Kindly help

[image: terminal command image]

I'm on ubuntu version 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I had OK with this Answer, https://askubuntu.com/a/858620/640587.

```
wget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

After finish running these command in terminal, check on an editor like as *LibreOffice*. You can find Microsoft font such as Arial, Comic Sans MS and so on.