# Extra fonts in 16.04

Tags: fonts

I've installed 16.04 but I don't see the extra package in Software for getting more fonts, do you know how to install it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you update your system after installing?

Comment: Yes, it took a while because the image was from 16.04, and not .1, but fonts are the same as before, not as with 14.04 with "extra package".

Comment: It may be easier to help you if you let us know which kind of fonts you are after. Is it fonts for rendering certain non-latin languages, is it proprietary Microsoft fonts, or...?

Comment: I'm looking after propietary fonts, I am used to them.

Comment: Then it's probably the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package you want. However, the current Ubuntu version of that package is buggy, so installing via Synaptic might fail. Please see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/858620) for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ubuntu Software* only shows applications, i.e. basically programs with a graphical UI. Help packages, such as extra fonts, can be installed from a terminal window. If you want a graphical interface to browse all available packages and install those extra fonts you want, you can install *Synaptic*.

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Comment: Thanks, and how could I install this package for extra fonts with the terminal?

Comment: @Roque: Via the command I suggested.

Comment: @Roque: Or did I misunderstand your question... Did you ask for a terminal command to install the extra fonts directly? Please note that there is not one package, there are approximately 200-300 different fonts packages...

Comment: I meant the package to install the fonts directly, but if there are hunders I'll have to install synaptic haha. Thanks.